# Not able to redirect to another HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

```js
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var server = require('http').createServer(app)
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var nodeSSPI = require('node-sspi')
  var nodeSSPIObj = new nodeSSPI({
    retrieveGroups: true
  })
  nodeSSPIObj.authenticate(req, res, function(err){
    res.finished || next()
  })
})
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  id  = req.connection.userSid
  res.redirect('Full_Name.html')
  res.send
})
// Start server
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000
server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on port %d in %s mode', port, app.get('env'))
})
```

I am new to node.js  . I am trying to redirect to a page after successfully login . but facing error

> localhost redirected you too many times.

and i dont know why but this javascript is not behaving same on firefox compared to other browsers .
I just want to redirect to `Full_Name.html` page after successfull login .

Answer (score 0):

Yeap, you are using [an express.js middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) without a route or any specific handling meaning that the redirect takes place across all the registered routes.

You may specify a redirect for a specific route as:

```
app.use('/redirect_me', function (req, res, next) {
  // This middleware is triggered across all methods
  // POST, GET, PUT etc;
  res.redirect('Full_Name.html');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to redirect to a route not to a page:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
id  = req.connection.userSid;
// do some check
res.redirect('/your-target-route');
next();
})

app.get('/your-target-route',function(req,res){
res.send('Full_Name.html');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
app.get('/Full_Name', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/Full_Name.html"); //path to ur file
});



res.redirect("/Full_Name");   //use wherever required

//You need to redirect the user to a webpage and not a file
```